# Width, height after second MaxPool2D is 1 less than downsampling factor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm fairly new to ML and creating NN's with Keras and TF, so I'm following the tutorial [here](https://keras.io/examples/vision/captcha_ocr/) to create a captcha ocr model, and slightly adapting the code for my own captcha images.

I'm using the following function to build the network:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

# image dimensions
image_width = 120
image_height = 40

# batch size for training and validation
batch_size = 16

def build_model():
  # inputs
  input_image = layers.Input(
      shape=(image_width, image_height, 1), name='image', dtype='float32'
  )
  labels = layers.Input(shape = (None,), name='label', dtype='float32')

  # first conv block
  x = layers.Conv2D(
      32,
      (3, 3),
      activation='relu',
      kernel_initializer='he_normal',
      padding='same',
      name='Conv1'
  )(input_image)
  x = layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2), name='Pool1')(x)
  print()

  # second conv block
  x = layers.Conv2D(
      64,
      (3, 3),
      activation='relu',
      kernel_initializer='he_normal',
      name='Conv2'
  )(x)
  x = layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2), name='Pool2')(x)

  # reshape
  new_shape = ((image_width // 4), (image_height // 4) * 64)
  x = layers.Reshape(target_shape=new_shape, name='Reshape')(x)
  x = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', name='Dense1')(x)
  x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)

  # recurrent block
  x = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.25))(x)
  x = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.25))(x)

  # output
  x = layers.Dense(11, activation='softmax', name='Dense2')(x)
  output = CTCLayer(name='CTCLoss')(labels, x)

  # define model
  model = keras.models.Model(
      inputs=[input_image, labels], outputs=output, name='CaptchaOCRv1'
  )
  model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam())
  return model
```

Given the input image dimensions (120, 40, 1) and two (2,2) pooling layers, I'd expect the shape at the input of the reshape layer to be (30, 10, 64). Yet I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged, input_shape = [29, 9, 64], output_shape = [30, 640]
```

I don't understand why the width and height are 1 less than the factor 4 downsampling. Can anyone point out my mistake?

Comment: You forgot `padding=same` in your second convolution.

Comment: @xdurch0 of course it was something stupid... thank you.